# asp.net mvc3 intellisense don't fire for css classes

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, class, razor, intellisense

In Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, MVC3, razor engine, _Layout.cshtml. If I reference CSS like this :

```
<link href="@Url.Content("/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

than intellisense don't work for css classes!
example :

```
<div class="<---- IntelliSense don't fire
```

But if i reference CSS like this :

```
<link href="/content/Site.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

than IntelliSense work.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the "why" is simple:  Visual Studio does not execute the call to Url.Content when discovering the CSS files.  VS executes *javascript* when evaluating JS expressions, but not for discovering files.

You are probably wondering how to get it to work...

Well, there doesn't really seem to be a good way, as of yet.  However, I cover one of the options (centered around JavaScript) on my blog:

http://otac0n.com/blog/2011/09/01/getting-javascript-intellisense-in-mvc-razor-views.html

This technique should work for CSS as well.

Comment: Hi John, I use something similiar to append aditional css from views, but problen still exists. This code `@section css_external {
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/ScrollerBX.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> }` also use @Url... As I see only solution is to use `<link href="/content/Site.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" /> ` and avoid `Url.Content`

Comment: What I was saying is that you have to use both.