# css intellisense not firing for class attribute in MVC 4 (VS12 Update 3, VS13 Preview)

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I have googled a lot to try to find a fix for this. But none of the discussion is helping me. Here is my situation.

For [him in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7767700/1306394). He says that css intellisense is working if he adds css like below. I am already using this method.

`<link href="~/Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

adding `type="text/css"` is also not working. I usually do not use this attribute but tried adding this when I saw in this question.

I also have both of these tools installed **[Web Essential 2012](http://vswebessentials.com)** and **Microsoft Web Developer Tools extension**.

Besides that, intellisense is working everywhere perfectly. It is also generating intellisense for HTML element, Razor expressions and even for JavaScript (jQuery too).

In the image below, there is no intellisense at current cursor location.

[image]

Please help me getting rid of this.

Added:
It won't generate list of css classes even if I add a few css classes in `<style></style` section.